# Rand() function cause error when I replace static value with random value

Tags: php

What am I doing wrong

I have this script, and added the `$randnumber = rand(100, 500);` function to it, this should generate a random number for me between 100 and 500.

```
   $randnumber = rand(100, 500);
    function word_limiter( $text, $limit = $randnumber, $chars = '0123456789' )
```

The problem is that it gives me a error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected
>   T_VARIABLE

While if I use the function as:

```
function word_limiter( $text, $limit = '200', $chars = '0123456789' )
```

it works 100%, I have tried it like this:

```
function word_limiter( $text, $limit = ''.$randnumber.'', $chars = '0123456789' )
```

but still get an error?

Comment: rand() is not actually that random, multiply 2 rand()'s from 0,10 and it's almost always = 10  better to use mt_rand()

Comment: what is the difference between rand() and mt_rand()?

Comment: from the mt_rand() docs: `Many random number generators of older libcs have dubious or unknown characteristics and are slow. By default, PHP uses the libc random number generator with the rand() function. The mt_rand() function is a drop-in replacement for this. It uses a random number generator with known characteristics using the » Mersenne Twister, which will produce random numbers four times faster than what the average libc rand() provides.`  i may of over exaggerated my previous comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a syntax error. You cannot assign the value of an expression as a default value. Default values can only be constants. Instead of doing that, you could be doing something like:

```php
function word_limiter ($text, $limit = null, $chars = '0123456789') {
    if ($limit === null) {
        $limit = rand(100, 500);
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing wrong is trying to use a variable as a default parameter value.  You cannot do this.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

```
function word_limiter( $text, $limit = null, $chars = '0123456789' ){
    if (is_null($limit)){
        $limit = rand(100, 500);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not use a variable as the default to an argument - it must be a constant value.

You could try this...

```
function word_limiter($text, $limit = NULL) {
   if ($limit === NULL) {
      // Make its default value.
   }
}
```